# Java scanner input validation

Tags: java, validation, input, java.util.scanner

I am trying to accept only three numbers from my input: 1, 2, 3. Any other different than that must be invalid. I have created method but I don't have an idea why it did not working. What must I change?

```
int number;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter 1, 2 or 3");
    while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    }
    number = scanner.nextInt();
} while (number == 1 || number == 2 || number == 3)
return number;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop logic

```
do {
    ...
} while (number == 1 || number == 2 || number == 3);
```

requires staying in the loop for as long as the answer is *valid*. You want to invert your condition:

```
do {
    ...
} while (!(number == 1 || number == 2 || number == 3));
```

or use [*De Morgan's Law*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to invert individual components:

```
do {
    ...
} while (number != 1 && number != 2 && number != 3);
```

In addition, when `Scanner`'s `hasNextInt` returns `false`, you need to take the invalid input off the scanner, for example with `nextLine` that you ignore. Otherwise you get an infinite loop:

```
while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    scanner.nextLine(); // This input is ignored
}
```

Comment: This is answer I am looking for. I will accept it after 11 minutes

Comment: bit there is problem. If I type letter start endless loop

Comment: @TeodorKolev Yep, that's what my edit was about :-)